# Finding a function $f(x)$ involved in a formula

Tags: calculus

If 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^x f(t) \text{ d}t = x \sec^2x + \int_{0}^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} \text{ d}t,
\end{align*}
find $f(x)$ ?!!

Comment: Usually, you would just differentiate both sides.

Comment: How @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: with product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is another "Do-my homework" question with zero effort shown.

Comment: I already have an answer but I want to make sure of. My idea is to differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ using the first fundamental theorem of calculus. @uniquesolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(x) = \sec^2 x + x (2 \sec^2 x \tan x) + \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\\
f(x) (1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} ) = \sec^2 x + x (2 \sec^2 x \tan x)\\
f(x) = (1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} )^{-1} (\sec^2 x + x (2 \sec^2 x \tan x))\\
$$